# create procedure with commit and rollback

Tags: mysql

I am writing a script to commit and rollback if the code should fail.  There are no errors with in the code and the code (I think) executes.  The problem is I am not seeing output from the code and I do not know if I should be seeing the code or how to see the code.

The 'UPDATE LISTINS' code will run but itself.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS displaylistingtest;    
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DISPLAYLISTINGTEST()
BEGIN
                DECLARE sql_error TINYINT Default false;
                DECLARE continue handler for sqlexception
                SET sql_error = true;
START TRANSACTION;
                UPDATE LISTINGS
                SET LISTING_PRICE = LISTING_PRICE +
                CASE
                WHEN LISTING_PRICE < 500000 THEN (LISTING_PRICE*1.05)/100
                WHEN LISTING_PRICE >= 500000 THEN (LISTING_PRICE*1.10)/100
                ELSE 0
                END;
IF sql_error = FALSE THEN
                COMMIT;
                SELECT 'the transaction was commited.';
                ELSE
                ROLLBACK;
SELECT 'the tranaction was rolled back.';
                END IF;
                CALL display_listing;
                END //
```

Comment: Why all of this in MySQL instead of in your application layer?

Comment: @ tadman, have no clue what the application layer (network) has to do with mysql, or maybe I am just mis-understanding your comment.

Comment: "Application layer" is something outside of MySQL that runs SQL commands, for example a .Net application, or a Python script, or *whatever* you want.

Comment: @tadman, because it is for a mysql class.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Comment: debuging n stored procdure start by adding user defined variables @a to @d and adding information to it and after runng the procedure chekc what it in it

Comment: @ nbk, sorry do you have an example, I have no clue what you mean.